# BaseActivity or Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Recently, I was placed on a project with another developer and he started our project with a `BaseActivity` (which extends `ActionBarActivity`), but when the app starts it runs `MainActivity` (which extends `BaseActivity`).

```
Activity Structure

BaseActivity = Parent
-- MainActivity = Child
-- AnotherActivity = Child
```

Wouldn't this be better practice to use `MainActivity` (which extends `ActionBarActivity`) and handle activity changes with `Fragment`s?

```
Activity Structure    

MainActivity = Parent
-- DrawerFragment = Child
-- GraphFragment = Child
```

*P.S. There are many external internet API calls that should be done at the "Parent" `Activity` level.*

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are there for bigger displays like tablets. They allow you to display more than one fragment on the screen if it s big enough. It doesn't have anything to do with API calls. In my opinion it s easier to work with fragments, but you have to ask yourself if it s worth your time to implement it.